# Array not paginateable (Shopify)

Tags: pagination, shopify

I've combined articles from all blogs into an array and I'm trying to paginate them but I'm getting this error "Liquid error: Array 'featuredArticles' is not paginateable."

```
{% assign featuredBlogs = "All,Products,Health,Training,Nutrition" | split: "," %}
    {% assign featuredArticles = false %}
    {% for featuredBlog in featuredBlogs %}
      {% if blogs[featuredBlog].articles %}
        {% if featuredArticles %}
          {% assign featuredArticles = featuredArticles | concat:blogs[featuredBlog].articles %}
        {% else %}
          {% assign featuredArticles = blogs[featuredBlog].articles %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% if featuredArticles %}
      {% assign featuredArticles = featuredArticles | sort:'published_at' | reverse %}
          {% paginate featuredArticles by 5 %}
            {% for article in featuredArticles %}
            <a href="{{ article.url }}" class="article-preview">
            <div class="article-pi-wrap">
              <img src="{{ article.image | img_url: 'medium' }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="ap-bottom">
              <h5 class="ap-title">{{ article.title }}</h5>
              <p class="ap-excerpt">
                <span>{{ article.published_at | date: format: 'abbreviated_date' }}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
            {% include "pagination" %}
          {% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Hi @Yum do you get any solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looping through array which is not available on that page or page specific object is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination will not work on an array of articles. It will work on on array of articles that is a property of the blog object.

That is to say:

```
{% assign _articles = blog.articles %}
{% paginate _articles by 6 %
```

Will not work, has to be:

```
  {% paginate blog.articles by 6 %
```

If you want to sort blog articles, and still have pagination, you will want to use javascript to implement the pagination and sorting.